# How to write an image stored in a byte[] to a file in google cloud storage?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I m trying to use Google Image service and I m trying out the follwing example to resize an image.

```
import com.google.appengine.api.images.Image;
import com.google.appengine.api.images.ImagesService;
import com.google.appengine.api.images.ImagesServiceFactory;
import com.google.appengine.api.images.Transform;

// ...
        byte[] oldImageData;  // ...

        ImagesService imagesService = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService();

        Image oldImage = ImagesServiceFactory.makeImage(oldImageData);
        Transform resize = ImagesServiceFactory.makeResize(200, 300);

        Image newImage = imagesService.applyTransform(resize, oldImage);

        byte[] newImageData = newImage.getImageData();
```

I m stuck at the point where I need to store the byte[] newImageData to a jpg file in google cloud storage. I know how to create a txt file but not a jpg.

Anybody could help me please?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know GAE  operates with bytes. The source/destination of the image data (your jpg) can be:  URL connection, DataStore BLOB or BlobStorage.
Don't forget you have to use pure Java.There can be several ways:

1. First try to use Jimi - it's pure Java library for working with images.Rather simple.
2. Also there exists an alpha version of the `appengine-awt` library:https://code.google.com/p/appengine-awt/source/checkout
   It will allow you to use standard `BufferedImage` but  there are a lot of bugs in it, so may be some problems.

But you still can use standard GAE Api for Images.There is an Image interface in which nested class Image.Format specified JPEG format.Method `setImageData(byte[] data)` will be useful for you.

Here is documentation on it: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/images/Image#setImageData(byte[])

Comment: thnx for your answer.
I tried to use Jimi. However I already have the image, that I want to write in file in Google Image format. I cannot cast it to JimiImage. In any case I dont want to use extra libraries.
setImadeData() method will create an Image object of my image, but I already have my image data in an Image object. 
I didnt try the appengine -awt cause i didnt find any good documentation. Could you please elaborate more on the "There is an Image interface in which nested class Image.Format specified JPEG format.Method setImageData(byte[] data) will be useful for you" statement?